# Fail2ban not sending email

Tags: mail, fail2ban

I set up Fail2ban as per this page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fail2ban

I tried looking in several pages among others: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25890510/fail2ban-not-sending-email-notifications
https://technicalramblings.com/blog/how-to-add-email-notifications-to-fail2ban/
https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/fail2ban-email-notifications.45597/

I went through lots of pages and different approaches. Problem seem to be this:
Some say you should edit jail.local under:
[iptables]
or
[ssh]
or
[sshd]
filter variations:
ssh
sshd
some say:
logpath: /var/log/auth.log
some don mention it at all, making me belive it should be default.
some say keep mta = mail
some say mta = sendmail
some say edit configuration files in action.d
Do I need mailutils installed?
I tried but made no difference.
some only mention jail.local
I check with:

```
cat /var/log/fail2ban.log
```

sendmail seems to send mails really really slowly. Read it probably has to do with stuff above my controll according to: 
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/sendmail-not-working-809318/

That could explain the ERRORS in above log stating:
timed out after 60 seconds.
Also get the ERROR Failed to execute ban jail 'sshd' action 'sendmail-whois'
apparently that can also take to much time.

I tried sending mail with sendmail using this syntax:

```
sendmail xx@xx
```

Followed by Subject: blabla
and the message here
. <---- to actually send the mail, dot needs to be on separate line.

But internally looking at some of the files in fail2ban it uses the syntax reminding of this:

```
echo " something something" | sendmail...
```

I tried this syntax manually. But then it sayes it doesnt have privileges...

**I know all this is messy**
I just want to show I really tried, several approaches several Howto's. Those times I thought of a possible reason, it has been above my knowledge of how to fix it.

**Basically, the question is:**
Using Latest Ubuntu Server
And having functioning ufw installed.
what EXACTLY to do, to make fail2ban send message to an e-mail address.
Not withholding information that might not be obvious to a noob like me

**Why this needed?**
As one of the several howto's stated: "Not another fail2ban howto?"
Reason for so many howto's about fail2ban could be:

- Lot of them is outdated
- They simply are wrong or skip stuff that need to be configured?
- Configuring it is lot more complicated then what people make it to be

So, I think a LOT of noobs like me and perhaps others as well would benefit of a detailed step by step explanation on WHAT exactly one needs to do command by command to make it work x).
On Ubuntu server 18.4.29

Best Regards!

Comment: What MTA are you using?

Comment: I am using sendmail. I tried sending just using sendmail. It took like 30-60 seconds for it to send (read somewhere it had to do with dns setting, something Im not in control of) but eventually a mail landed in my hotmail account.